# displaying mobile nav in desktop view bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the mobile navigation in desktop view in bootstrap. so I set the container to 328px but I can't get the button so the nav will toggle.

How can I do that?

http://postimg.org/image/6nbrsga19/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set a width to the container to check it. remove the width from the container.

You just need to resize your browser window. Thats it.